# how to write a string which starts with - into csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to write data to CSV file.

The string value which starts with `-` is getting converted to `#NAME?` automatically when i open csv file after writing. e.g. If i write `test` it displays correctly but when i write `-test` the value would be `#NAME?` when i open csv file. It is not a code issue but csv file automatically changes the value which starts with `-` to `error(#NAME?)`. How can i correct this programmatically. below is the code,

```
public class FileWriterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        File file = new File("test.csv");
        try {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            List<String> records = getRecords();
            for (String record : records) {
                bufferedWriter.write(record);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            System.out.println("Completed writing data to a file.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bufferedWriter != null)
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getRecords() {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s1 = "test";
        String s2 = "-test";
        al.add(s1);
        al.add(s2);
        return al;
    }
}
```

Could you please assist?

Comment: who shows #name? IS it excel?

Comment: that is formula conversion which is excel functionality

Comment: @Veslin. When i open csv file using excel it shows #name.

Comment: Open it in a text editor first, to see if `#NAME` is really written there. I'd guess the `#NAME` you're seeing is the result of excel trying to evaluate it as an expression

Comment: In text editor value is proper i.e -test. We need to provide the resultant data file to client where they open it in excel so i would like to know if we can suppress the excel formula through code not to convert it to error in case of string starts with -.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with excel. When you open a CSV file in excel it tries to determine cell type automatically which usually fails. The CSV file is alright the editor is not ;)

You can either right click on the field, select Format Cell and there make it a text file (and you might need to remove the automatically inserted '=' sign). Or you can open the CSV file by going into Data - From Text/CSV and in the wizard select the proper column types.

Comment: Again its a manual effort right? Is there any other alternatives to correct it through programmatically before writing. Because client may not do this manual effort with the files we provide to them.

Comment: All you can do is write the CSV file according to the CSV standard (which you did) If the client wants to use Excel as a tool its his decision and he should be the one take care of flaws in excel. What if the next client wants to use some strange tool that shows CSV backwards? You just follow the standard...

Answer (score 1):

In the [formal CSV standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), you can do this by using quotes (`"`) around the field value. They're a text delimiter (as opposed to other kinds of values, like numeric ones).

It sounds like you're using Excel. You may need to enable `"` as a text delimiter/indicator.

**Update:** If you double-click the .csv to open it in Excel, even this doesn't work. You have to open a workbook and then import the CSV data into it. (Pathetic, really...)

Comment: @VeselinDavidov: Just tested it with Excel 2016, worked just fine.

Comment: hmm maybe depends on the version

Comment: @VeselinDavidov: Just dug deeper: It depends on how you open it. If you double-click the .csv file, it fails (even with the qutoes). If you open a workbook and import from CSV, it works properly. C'mon Microsoft, pull it together... :-)

Comment: Yeah it's the automatically determening of the column types.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov: And you'd think a standard text qualifier would help it understand the column is text! :-)

Comment: I wouldn't think so. I have had the great 'pleasure' to deal with customers using Excel for opening CSV files and calling for help and I had seen it all..

Answer (score -1):

I got a relatively old version of Excel (2007), and the following works perfectly:

Put the text between double quotes and preceed it with an equal sign.
I.e., `-test` becomes `="-test"`.

You file will therefore look like this:

```
test1,test2,test3
test4,="-test5",test6
```

**UPDATE**
Works in Excel-2010 as well.

As Veselin Davidov mentioned, this will break the csv standard but I don't know whether that's a problem.

Comment: Yeah and in this case you break the CSV format and if you open that file with any other CSV editor instead of excel 2007 it works bad.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov OP said he's opening with Excel.

Comment: Yeah but still it is a standard and having .csv file that has some strange values in that breaks the standard. If he is only using it for excel he can make it xslx

Comment: @VeselinDavidov: Creating an xlsx is a bit more complicated, even if you use apache-poi. Depends on the needs of the OP